# Connect to MySQL v8+ (Docker CE) using MySQL a v5.7 MySQL client (Ubuntu)?

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run a MySQL database in a Docker container and connect to it from the host machine. What I do is:

installing MySQL on Ubuntu host:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

The version is 5.7.11, I then install Docker CE as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). To run my MySQL and get the IP server I do:

```
docker run --detach --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" mysql
docker inspect test-mysql | grep IPAddress
```

I then try to connect to the MySQL database with:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h 172.17.0.2 -P 3306
```

And is greeted by the following:

```
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be 
loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared 
object file: No such file or directory
```

I've understood that there has been [changes to MySQL Authentication](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/). It's for 8.0.4 and the version on the [Docker image for MySQL](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/) seems to be 8.0.11, so I believe it's relevant.

I realise that I can run an earlier version of the MySQL image as so, for example:

```
docker run --detach --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" mysql:5
```

Indeed this will let me log on to the Docker Container's MySQL. I suspect I could also install a newer MySQL version, as [described here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04).

But I'd like to understand what the problem is and I'm not sure I actually have the option to switch versions around. So my questions are:

- Why can't I log on is it the older MySQL version which does not support the new authentication protocol?
- Is it possible to log on to the Docker container using this combination by changing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` under the `[mysqld]` section of the MySQL 8's server (or use `mysqld --default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` in your `entrypoint/exec` Docker command).

This will allow MySQL 5.7 clients to connect using the legacy `mysql_native_password` plugin. To be safe, create the user to specifically use the `mysql_native_password` plugin, for example:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```